# Where is memory definitely lost here?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have made a function in C that handles [write callback](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) from cURL.

```
static size_t writecallback(char* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, char** stream) {
    size_t csize=size*nmemb;
    size_t psize = strlen(*stream);
    size_t tsize = csize+ psize;
    *stream = (char*)realloc(*stream, tsize+1);
    memcpy(*stream + psize, contents,csize);
    (*stream)[tsize] = '\0';
    return csize;
}
```

I don't know how to write in C correctly, I got lost memory here. I used valgrind to check for memory leak, report message looked something like this:

```
906 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 859 of 931
at 0x4848B80: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1690)
```

I tried using chatgpt but it didn't help me much.

With that function I do this ( reproducible example ):

```
char* request(){
    CURL* curl=curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist* header=NULL;

    char* output=malloc(1);
    output[0]='\0';
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writecallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &output);
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res!=CURLE_OK){
        printf("Failed performing actions,\n%s\n",       
        curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    return output;
}
const char* out=request();
//forward logic here
```

Sorry I don't really know how to write reproducible examples.

What to do here?
What did I do wrong?
Can you please tell me what did I do wrong so I will know for next time?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: The answer will depend on what the callback is supposed to do. Can you include a link to some relevant docs?

Comment: @OLEGSHA I've added a link to the documentation of `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`

Comment: Where do you free the memory? Can you put together a [mcve]?

Comment: ok i will put reproducible example.

Comment: Whatever `*stream` points to needs to be freed when you're done.

Comment: I wrote a reproducible example there.

Comment: When realloc fails, it return null. You lose the original memory in that case.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica why would realloc fail?

Comment: Same reason any allocator fails, it can't provide a block of the requested size for w/e reason

Comment: Was I supposed to make a sort of temporary for stream there?

Comment: Yes. The correct idiomatic use of realloc is `void* tmp = realloc(...); if(tmp) actual = tmp;`

Comment: Your `writecallback` function has the wrong signature. I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo what does that mean?

Comment: It means that `char** stream` should be `void *userdata`. The name isn't important, but the type is. Those two pointer types could have different sizes. So switch the type, and use `char** stream = userdata;` in the function.

Comment: Thanks, but Valgrind report didn't change at all.

Comment: Correct. It's an unrelated issue.

Comment: A [mcve] is something that someone could copy/paste/compile/run on their own to duplicate the issue. The code shown in the question is not that, it is incomplete. You're asking about leaked or lost memory yet the example doesn't show the full lifecycle of that allocated memory. Do you free it at some point? Does the pointer you have to it go out of scope or is it reassigned without freeing the memory?

Comment: Any code using `strlen` is probably wrong. This likely doubly so. You'd want your `userdata` have a structure that contains the allocated length *and* the amount of bytes thus written. Your code will not work when there are embedded nulls and is slow otherwise, see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deallocate memory that you allocate after you're done with it. You're missing `free( out );`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, there are a couple of unrelated issues.

- `char**` might not be compatible with `void *`. They could even have different sizes! That is why

  ```c
  static size_t writecallback( ..., char **stream ) {
     ...
  }
  ```

  should be

  ```c
  static size_t writecallback( ..., void *userdata ) {
     char **stream = userdata;
     ...
  }
  ```

  The assignment will generate the proper code for converting the `void*` back into a `char**`.
- `realloc` could return `NULL`. On a machine with virtual memory, this means your program will crash if you run out of memory. That's probably fine, but it would be best to provide a relevant error message. But if this program is to run on a machine without virtual memory, this is something you need to handle.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I forgot to add the return line there in request function.I used const char* there. Isn't it the same as free? Do I need to add a free in the request() function? Isn't it that I returned the pointer and if I free it the program wouldn't work? I tried to run it and now it doesn't show that memory loss again. But it shows invalid read size of 1 in the logic part of that reproducible example I put there.

Comment: Re "*I used const char* there. Isn't it the same as free?*", `const char*` is a type. `free` is a function that frees memory. Apples and sneezes.

Comment: Re "*Isn't it that I returned the pointer and if I free it the program wouldn't work?*", The program does work. But it leaks memory. This should be fixed.

Comment: How do I fix that memory leak?

Comment: Free the memory block you've allocated using `free`, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Now I get that kinds of error:
```Address 0x684e2d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 906 free'd
==4679==    at 0x484488F: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:985)```
That happens in logic part of reproducible example.
Shoud I just skip them?

Comment: Free the memory *after* you're done with it.

Comment: I already done that. Wait can I just ask it so we on same thing: So there's a malloc in that request function to pointer called output. And then after cURL is done with it, I return from the function the output pointer. I use ```char* out=request();``` And in logic part I use it and then free it. Is that correct?

Comment: @LimeStone **1** `malloc` **2** use the allocated memory **3** `free` the allocated memory **4** don't access the previously allocated memory again, it is gone. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P3rc485cb) of what it could look like

Comment: Re "*I already done that.*", No, you used the memory after freeing it. That makes no sense.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if I do like you said it returns same error as at the start:
```906 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 860 of 932
==4824==    at 0x4848B80: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1690)```

Comment: @LimeStone Then you don't `free` everything you've allocated.

Comment: @Lime Stone Look, these error messages mention lines 985 and 1690 of a program you haven't shown. As such, we can't comment on your bugs any further than we did. If you have any further questions, post it as a Question, including the exact code that you ran to get the error message. (The code should be as short as possible.) You have claimed the existance of a "reproduceable example", but you have yet to provide any runnable code.

Comment: You are probably right, any things in that logic part that I have not shown are probably causing the issue. I removed them and memory leak is lower, or it's not there anymore. I will try to take a look at that logic part. Except that I got lost there so I rather not continue. Sorry for any problems that I have made. Thanks and have a good day.